Prove that area bounded by the graph is less than $\sqrt2$
Let $y = g(x)$ be a real valued function and $g'(x)$ is a continuous function such that $g'(x) \geq 0$ and $g(0) = 0$, $g(1) = 1$ and if the area bounded by $y = \sqrt{1+(g'(x))^2}$, $x = 0$, $x = 1$ and the x-axis is $S$, then prove that $S\leq\sqrt2$.
I can only think of examples like $g(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, but cannot prove this for the "general case".

Can you think about the function for which the "maximum" $\sqrt{2}$ is attained? Write down a mathematical formula for the quantity that you call "the area bounded by $y = ...,x=0,x=1$ and the $x$-axis".

@SarveshRavichandranIyer , $g(x)=x$

Your inequality points in the wrong direction! Not that the statement is follows nicely from the fact that the shortest path between two points in the euclidean plane is a straight line. Hence the minimum is achieved iff the graph of g is a straight line.

@M.E.W. , but aren't we talking about $\sqrt{1+(g'(x))^2}$

I think we know $\sqrt{2} \leq S \leq 2.$

Yea, integrate it and you get the length of the curve defined by g.

@M.E.W. , so it might be a typo in my textbook but the question does clearly state $ \leq \sqrt(2)$. But I'm convinced with ur answer.

Ok to check your result simply take desmos and calculate the area numerically for $g(x)=x^n$ and pick a large value of $n$. Then $S$ will be slightly less than 2 (like 1.99 ish).

For $g(x)=x^a$, there is a formal result.  For $a=100$, $1.95167$.  For $a=1000$, $1.99280$. For $a=10000$, $1.99905$.

Let $\alpha(x)=(x,g(x))$ for $x\in[0,1]$. For each unit vector $u$ you have:
$$(\alpha(1)-\alpha(0))\cdot u=\int_0^1 \alpha'(x)\cdot u \, \mathrm dx \le\int_0^1 \lvert \alpha'(x)\rvert \, \mathrm dx $$
Now, if you choose $u=\frac{\alpha(1)-\alpha(0)}{\lvert\alpha(1)-\alpha(0) \rvert}$ you get:
$$(\alpha(1)-\alpha(0))\cdot \frac{\alpha(1)-\alpha(0)}{\lvert\alpha(1)-\alpha(0) \rvert}=\frac1{\sqrt 2}(1,1)  \cdot (1,1)=\sqrt 2$$
Hence
$$\sqrt 2\le \int_0^1 \lvert \alpha'(x)\rvert \, \mathrm dx=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(g'(x))^2} \, \mathrm dx=:S $$
